# Lanzar una función con addEventListener cuando un campo de texto muestre un valor determiando

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy intentando conseguir que una función se lance cuando el evento que genere el lanzamiento sea que un `input type="text"` muestre un valor determinado que se modifica como consecuencia de la ejecución de otra función (esto ya está hecho, no es problema).
No he visto ningún evento que sirva para dispararse cuando se obtenga un `document.getElementById("campoTexto").value`, o algo parecido.

Comment: if(document.getElementById("campoTexto").value == "x"){...codigo...}    No hace falta un evento para ello, basta con un if, al menos, con lo que te estoy entendiendo. Sino, pon la parte de código que ya tienes y seguramente sea más sencillo

Comment: Creo que tienes suficiente puntaje para saber como se hace una pregunta jej pero aun así por acá te dejo [como preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) por favor edita tu pregunta para que no seas puntuado negativamente y podamos ayudarte, no te desanimes, un saludo.

Comment: Creo que este es el daño que hace el trabajar y aprender frameworks y librerias de js antes de aprender js, que sueles pensar que cosas así son implícitas jaja pero ni si quiera el enfoque es correcto, el evento que buscas se llama keypress, keydown, keyup, etc. La cosa es que debes evaluar en la función del evento para comprobar si se puede disparar.

Comment: *.. evento que sirva para dispararse cuando se obtenga un document.getElementById("campoTexto").value, ..* Esto revela un desconocimiento de [lo que son los **Eventos**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events), como ya señalan otros compañeros en sus comentarios. El `value` no es un evento, el evento sería algún cambio o acción, como que se pulse una tecla sobre 1 elemento, se haga click, que cambie, etc. Son esos los eventos que son escuchados y cuando los mismos ocurren entonces puedes lanzar el código que sea, obtener el `value` o en ese momento, etc.

Comment: Muchas gracias por vuestros comentarios y vuestra ayuda, recordándome que debo ahondar en el estudio de JS. Creo que he encontrado la solución con el primer comentario, con un IF. Genial este aporte

Comment: @A.Cedano y es que esto pasa por cosas como las que hace vue con v-model, las personas que ven esto y lo aprenden no saben por que el valor es reactivo con v-model cosa que no está mal, lo que está mal es leer el libro de atras para adelante, actualmente siento que está pasando exactamente lo mismo que pasaba con jquery ahora con frameworks modernos, la gente aprendia jquery no javascript.

Comment: @DєηyηCrawford ya. Realmente nunca he usado Vue, por tanto no tenía ni idea sobre este comportamiento. Tienes razón en lo que dices, a mi me ocurrió al principio con jQuery, hasta que descubrí [sitios como este](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/) que me hicieron interesarme más por Javascript puro. Y algo parecido me pasó muy al principio con Wordpress, hasta que pude conectar mi contenido en background con PHP puro lo cual me libró de tener que usar un plugin para cada cosa con la lentitud y problemas de seguridad que ello supone.

Comment: Eso es genial, deberían actualizar esa web, actualmente hay apis mas avanzadas como fetch y todas tienen pollyfills, realmente no veo ya la necesidad de soportar esos navegadores obsoletos, realmente hay que hacer trabajo extra solo por el mal trabajo que se hizo con Explorer, pero bueno eso es otro tema... Te invito a que respondas tu propia pregunta si encontraste la solución, un saludo.

Comment: No me quiero entrometer en vuesta conversación Cedano y Crawford, para mí tiene mucho nivel y no llego a tanto. Sólo, al hilo del primer comentario de Crawford, al que le he agradecido con toda franqueza que me recuerde que debo estudiar más JS, sólo me gustaría aclara que no conozco Vue y no me gusta jQuery, soy muy purista y me gusta aprender siempre el fondo del asunto (de los lenguajes puros), para luego saber bien qué es lo que estás haciendo. Lo único que ocurre es que llevo mucho tiempo sin tocar código y las cosas se me han olvidado, así es que me toca, de nuevo, casi empezar de cero.